# Unable to parse string for Int64 in pd read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

It doesn't seem as if Pandas 2.0.0 properly accounts for `thousands=','` when parsing `Int64` objects:

```
import io
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''a\n22,922'''), sep='\t', dtype={'a': 'Int64'}, thousands=',')
```

The specific error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File pandas/_libs/lib.pyx:2280 in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric    
ValueError: Unable to parse string "22,922"
```

Is there a work around that doesn't involve going back to un-nullable `int` or converting to `float`? I've confirmed this works for the old dtypes `dtype={'a': 'int'}` and `dtype={'a': 'float'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the error will be triggered even if you don't specify a `thousands` argument. That's an open issue (*see* [*GH52594*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52594)). You can't apply yet a [nullable dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) when calling [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with the `C` engine.

A simple workaround would be to use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) :

```
(
    pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO('''a\n22,922'''), sep='\t', thousands=',')
        .astype(dtype={'a': 'Int64'}) # add this line
)

       a
0  22922
```

Answer (score 2):

The default engine is `c`, you want to use `python`

```
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''a\n22,922'''), sep='\t', dtype={'a': 'Int64'}, thousands=',', engine='python')
```

Output

```
       a
0  22922
```